# How Many Top Words We Have to Select from Each Text File in Order to Get the Top k Words of the Corpus

Tags: count, cpu-word, mergesort

If I have a corpus containing 100 articles, and each article has a lot of words, so I want to count each article independently on different threads or in distributed system.

So for each article I will get a list of words sorted by word frequency, something like (in C++):

```
//         count, word
vector<pair<int, string> > v0;
sort(v0.begin(), v0.end(), greater<pair<int, string> >); // descending order
```

For the other 99 articles, we will get similar sorted results, `v1, v2, ... v99`

My question is, how do we merge sort the result to get the top `k` (say 10) words in the corpus?

NOTE: this corpus might be in a distributed system, we may not want to get all words from each list, so the question becomes: how many top words we have to select from each article in order to get the top `k=10` words of the entire corpus? In order words, can we discard any words from each article?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). There is also [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480391/how-can-i-find-only-interesting-words-from-a-corpus), which was answered a couple of years back.